# solaris process is running but the java program seems stucked

Tags: java, unix, process, solaris

I have a script (in solaris) which will call a java program to read the data from xml file and insert/update into oracle database, and it will print out the details into a log file. This script is scheduled in crontab to run daily.
The log basically will record the job started time, what data has been inserted/updated into db, and job ended time if the job ended successfully, and will print out exception message if error occur.
Recently I am facing a issue where by cannot found any error message and job ended time from the log, seems like the job just "die" in the half way? and found out that the job's process is still running. Anyone can advice why this will happen?

update: when i rerun the script, the job is ended successfully. But the previous process id still stuck there when i do ps -ef

Comment: What does `pstack PID` show, where PID is the process iD of the "stuck" process?

Comment: Can you look for child processes of your PID with `ps -ef`? Is the pid waiting for a subprocess? Does it consume CPU-time? Can you copy the script into a debugging one, change what is needed for the next experiment: start script by crontab every 5 minutes. Does it occur again?